# Why do I get a different subnet on VPN?

Tags: vpn, remote-access

I've set up a VPN on my router, Asus AC66U. The VPN works, I
 can get an IP and it works fine for browsing the network.

When I connect I get a different subnet (`255.255.255.255`) then the local network, (`255.255.255.0`). Can I change this?  I want access to the other computers in the local net (shares).

Or is there a way to connect the subnets?

Answer (score 0):

Once you connect through the VPN you can access local computers via Remote Desktop Connection using their local IP, assuming you are using windows (you didn't indicate what platform your running on).

Comment: Im on win8rt, want to access my media shares from the rest og the world